# How to pass strings from command line through a socket connection

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying and failing to adapt some code that passes an int matrix into something that will pass through command line arguments. What do I need to do to pass strings over sockets?
I'm using Debian.

Attached is the original code I'm working with that just creates and sends an array of squares of the first 30 numbers and prints basic acceptance info.

Command line inputs would look like

Server: `./Server_code <port>`

Client: `./Client_code <address> <port> [arg1] [arg2] [arg3] [argn]`

All I want to do is send the arguments to the server to be processed.

Client_Code

```
/* Client code */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAXDATASIZE 100 /* max number of bytes we can get at once */

#define ARRAY_SIZE 30

void Send_Array_Data(int socket_id, int *myArray)
{
    int i = 0;
    uint16_t statistics;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        statistics = htons(myArray[i]);
        send(socket_id, &statistics, sizeof(uint16_t), 0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, numbytes, i = 0;
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    struct hostent *he;
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr; /* connector's address information */

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: client_hostname port_number\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((he = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL)
    { /* get the host info */
        herror("gethostbyname");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* clear address struct */
    memset(&their_addr, 0, sizeof(their_addr));

    their_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;            /* host byte order */
    their_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2])); /* short, network byte order */
    their_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr,
                sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Create an array of squares of first 30 whole numbers */
    int simpleArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
    {
        simpleArray[i] = i * i;
    }

    Send_Array_Data(sockfd, simpleArray);

    /* Receive message back from server */
    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }

    buf[numbytes] = '\0';

    buf[numbytes] = '\0';

    printf("Received: %s", buf);

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
```

Server_Code

```
/* Server Code */
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 30 /* Size of array to receive */

#define BACKLOG 10 /* how many pending connections queue will hold */

#define RETURNED_ERROR -1

int *Receive_Array_Int_Data(int socket_identifier, int size)
{
    int number_of_bytes, i = 0;
    uint16_t statistics;

    int *results = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if ((number_of_bytes = recv(socket_identifier, &statistics, sizeof(uint16_t), 0)) == RETURNED_ERROR)
        {
            perror("rec");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        results[i] = ntohs(statistics);
    }
    return results;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, new_fd;            /* listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd */
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;    /* my address information */
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr; /* connector's address information */
    socklen_t sin_size;
    int i = 0;

    /* Get port number for server to listen on */
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: port_number\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* generate the socket */
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Enable address/port reuse, useful for server development */
    int opt_enable = 1;
    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt_enable, sizeof(opt_enable));
    setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &opt_enable, sizeof(opt_enable));

    /* clear address struct */
    memset(&my_addr, 0, sizeof(my_addr));

    /* generate the end point */
    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;            /* host byte order */
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1])); /* short, network byte order */
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;    /* auto-fill with my IP */

    /* bind the socket to the end point */
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* start listnening */
    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server starts listnening ...\n");

    /* repeat: accept, send, close the connection */
    /* for every accepted connection, use a sepetate process or thread to serve it */
    while (1)
    { /* main accept() loop */
        sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        if ((new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr,
                             &sin_size)) == -1)
        {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n",
               inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr));
        if (!fork())
        { /* this is the child process */

            /* Call method to recieve array data */
            int *results = Receive_Array_Int_Data(new_fd, ARRAY_SIZE);

            /* Print out the array results sent by client */
            for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
            {
                printf("Value of index[%d] = %d\n", i, results[i]);
            }

            free(results);

            if (send(new_fd, "All of array data received by server\n", 40, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            close(new_fd); /* parent doesn't need this */
        }
        while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0)
            ; /* clean up child processes */
    }
}
```

Comment: if you know how to pass string through the socket connection, all you need to know is that command line arguments in C are : `int argc` and `char *argv[]`. with `argv` being an array of arguments and `argc` is a length of the array.